# Android TextView : Need text selection on Long Press not just double tap

Tags: android, textview, selection

I have a `TextView` that is supposed to be clickable, `selectable` and `linkified`. Up until a month ago, setting

```
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true); 
textView.setMovementMethod(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

would cause long press to show the `copy/paste` actions in the `Actionbar`. But now somehow, the `copy/paste` only shows on double tap and not on long press. Long press does nothing.
I really need for it to show on long press and not on double tap. Please help !!!

Comment: So, what changed a month ago? If you're not sure, would you provide more details, please? `TextView.setTextIsSelectable` is the only method you need to utilize the CAB for copying/pasting, whether it's via long press or double tap.

Comment: Some code did change in that adapter but nothing related to this. Does ordering of the method calls - setTextIsSelectable, setting onclick listener on the textview matter ? I tried commenting out the click listener, but that didnt help. The CAB only shows on double tap.

Comment: It would probably be easier if you posted all the code relating to `textView`.

Comment: did you clean your project?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Figured it out. There was a long click listener on the listview which was not doing anything since there was no long press defined for the listview. Although the clicks were properly delegated first to the textview before the list, the long presses were not. So in the onItemLongClick method, I return false to allow propogation to the textview